# What can cause these DBD::SQLite errors?

Tags: perl, dbi, dbd

I have an application inserting data into a sqlite database. Every so often I get these errors and I don't know why.

```
DBD::SQLite::st execute failed: database is locked at ...
```

or

```
DBD::SQLite::st execute failed: file is encrypted or is not a database
```

It's doing a bunch of inserts but sometimes it fails like this.

Comment: Have you checked file permissions?

Comment: File permissions are not changing when the application is running. Other inserts work fine.

Comment: 1. Do you have multiple threads/processes inserting? 2. Is the file on a network share?

Comment: Yeah it's on a Unix NFS. After reading some docs I saw "POSIX advisory locking is known to be buggy or even unimplemented on many NFS implementations" so I guess it's out of my control?